# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'int' en 'Android.Widget.ImageView'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

estoy empezando a meterme al mundo de C# con Android y me e topado con este problema que no e podido resolver. Espero que puedo me puedan orientar.

> Error CS0266  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'int' en 'Android.Widget.ImageView'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)

Mi código:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        int numero, numero2;
        ImageView imagen1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice1);
        ImageView imagen2 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice2);

        Button botonP = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRoll);

        Random ran = new Random();

        // Error aquí
        ImageView[] MyImagen = new ImageView[] {
            Resource.Drawable.uno,
            Resource.Drawable.dos,
            Resource.Drawable.tres,
            Resource.Drawable.cuatro,
            Resource.Drawable.cinco,
            Resource.Drawable.seis
        };

        Console.Write(MyImagen);
        botonP.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            numero = ran.Next(0, 6);
            numero2 = ran.Next(0, 6);
            imagen1.SetImageDrawable(MyImagen[numero]);
            //Toast mensaje = Menssage(numero);
            //mensaje.Show();

        };
    }
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El error parece estar aca: ImageView imagen1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice1); en si lo que dice es claro, estas tratando de convertir un entero en un imageview.

Comment: Has probado a hacer un casting a la hora de meter los objetos al array MyImagen? Algo similar a lo que haces al inicializar las variables imagen1 e imagen 2, al menos en java hay que hacerlo. Una sugerencia, las variables como MyImagen (no es un estandar pero es una costumbre muy extendida) se empiezan por minúscula.

Comment: Gracias @PabloSimonDiEstefano por tu comentario, al principio eso creia pero despues de investigar y probar y probar llegue a la solución que publique mas abajo. Encuanto a la variable amm no se en que esta pensando. Saludos !!

Answer (score 2):

Modificando mi codigo (prueba y error), llegue a la siguiente solución:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        int numero, numero2;
        ImageView imagen1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice1);
        ImageView imagen2 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice2);

        Button botonP = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRoll);

        Random ran = new Random();

        int[] myImage = {
            Resource.Drawable.uno,
            Resource.Drawable.dos,
            Resource.Drawable.tres,
            Resource.Drawable.cuatro,
            Resource.Drawable.cinco,
            Resource.Drawable.seis
        };


        botonP.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {

            numero = ran.Next(0, 6);

            numero2 = ran.Next(0, 6);
            Console.WriteLine(numero + " " + numero2);
            imagen1.SetImageResource(myImage[numero]);
            imagen2.SetImageResource(myImage[numero2]);

        };
    }
```